# Synchronous Call to REST on Contact update

Tags: salesforce-classic

We have a requirement to update back-end (using REST) system when a contact is updated. Using triggers we cannot  call webservice synchronously.
Is there a way we can implement this other than customizing the edit page with visual-force page.

Answer (score 0):

Different ways one can make calls synchronously:

1. A custom Visualforce page or button initiates an Apex SOAP callout in a synchronous manner.
2. A custom Visualforce page or button initiates an Apex HTTP callout in a synchronous manner.
3. A trigger that’s invoked from Salesforce data changes performs an Apex SOAP or HTTP callout in a synchronous manner.
4. **A batch Apex job performs an Apex SOAP or HTTP callout in a synchronous manner.**

May be option 4 is what you might be looking for.

More info on making calls synchronous here : [Remote Process Invocation—Request and Reply](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_remote_process_invocation_state.htm)

Comment: #3 is not correct. You cannot make a callout from trigger in synchronous way. It has to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using the standard "Edit" button, you don't have a way to make a callout synchronously. Even if you write a trigger, you [cannot make a callout from trigger synchronously](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000176570&type=1).

Not completely sure about your use case, as if you want to make a callout every time a contact record is updated or only specific field. But if you can split the update operation to make the callout only when specific fields are updated instead of the whole record, then you can introduce a custom button using a VF page or Lightning component, to update those specific fields and then invoke the web service callout synchronously. This way you can still continue using the standard edit operation on the contact with minimal change by utilizing a custom button.

If that's not what you need, then you will need to either make the callout asynchronously or customize your overall Edit operation.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have your reasons. But most of the times (if not all), synchronous call-outs are detrimental to user experience. 

I would rather keep that async and show the status of back-end updates - that gives the perception that the performance is better even though the back-end operations can take the same time.